# Is type-based metaprogramming (type to type transformation) possible in Rust?

Tags: rust

Consider the following toy example:

```rust
struct SignedAndUnsigned<S, U> {
    s: S,
    u: U,
}

type SignedAndUnsignedInteger = SignedAndUnsigned<i32, u32>;
type SignedAndUnsignedDouble  = SignedAndUnsigned<f64, f64>;
```

Here, I have some type `S` for a "signed" type, and another type `U` for an "unsigned" type. I can declare them together easily enough, but in more complicated cases, it might be useful to include only a single generic parameter, and compute the other parameter's type from that:

```rust
struct SignedAndUnsigned<S> {
    s: S,
    u: <???>
}
```

In C++, this could be accomplished through the use of something like type traits; e.g.

```cpp
template <typename S>
class SignedAndUnsigned {
    S s;
    typename std::make_unsigned<S>::type u;
}
```

Is something similar possible in Rust?

Answer (score 3):

Something similar can be accomplished with traits. For example:

```rust
trait SignedType {
    type UnsignedType;
}

impl SignedType for i32 {
    type UnsignedType = u32;
}

// ... other impls for other signed types ...

struct SignedAndUnsigned<S> where S: SignedType {
    signed: S,
    unsigned: <S as SignedType>::UnsignedType,
}

type SignedAndUnsignedInteger = SignedAndUnsigned<i32>;
```

There are a few restrictions, which (IIUC) is required to avoid some of the complexities that C++ has with SFINAE. In particular, the generic type `S` needs to be constrained by some trait providing the necessary type mappings.